# MLPClassifer status when fitting the model

Tags: python

When I am Training Using Neural Network I want to see the Progress For that reason in MLPClassifier() function I wrote verbose = True and after that I use fit() function.Now it shows:

RUNNING THE L-BFGS-B CODE

```
       * * *
```

Machine precision = 2.220D-16
 N =       344079     M =           10
 This problem is unconstrained.

At X0         0 variables are exactly at the bounds

At iterate    0    f=  2.70346D+00    |proj g|=  1.94826D-01

At iterate    1    f=  2.41155D+00    |proj g|=  1.19097D-01

At iterate    2    f=  2.11866D+00    |proj g|=  1.55296D-01

At iterate    3    f=  1.95068D+00    |proj g|=  1.00021D-01

At iterate    4    f=  1.84819D+00    |proj g|=  1.57815D-01

I didn't understand the meaning..
Thanks in advance